# How to find out Spring default bean Registrations

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, configuration

We have the following XML elements.

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:component-scan />
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

etc,

Is there a way to find out (from eclipse or any other method), what classes these configs load/register by default? Or is there a documentation on this one? (I know we can go through spring reference. But its spread across to be able to use this as a reference)

Comment: The spring reference is your best bet. The javadoc for the Java equivalent annotations might also be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the laziest way to do it is to crank up the log4j level for the org.springframework logger to TRACE. (i.e. the Log4j equivalent of turning it to 11 :) It will report what beans are loaded into the context.

Comment: Any code samples? I want to see not only user beans, but all  Framework beans as well.